# How to change C# Identity Login page default route

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, identity

I created a new project using `Microsoft.Aspnet.Identity.samples` for my authentication system.

As you know Visual Studio adds `AccountController` automatically to the project.

I just edited the Login action route using `[Route("login")]` attribute.

I added another Controller to my project called `Dashboard` with an `Index` method. Then I added an `[Authorize]` attribute to my dashboard controller.

When I call the URL `https://localhost/Dashboard/Index` and my request is not authenticated, the project authomaticaly redirects to `https://localhost/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fdashboard` and as I said I changed the Login route then my project gives me an error.

How can I change the default login URL?

Comment: You are sending a cookie which is causing the redirection.  Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and look at the headers in the first request to see what is happening.  The content type which is the type of browser may be causing an issue.  The server may not be accepting the default browser so you may need to add./change some of the default headers.  c# default header may not work with the server. Best way of debugging is to compare a working app with non working and compare the headers in 1st request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the file `Startup.Auth.cs` is a method called `ConfigureAuth` you can change the login path default to your custom route.